# Can't convert string to number

Tags: javascript

I have a large text from which I read data according to the scheme. Key words are placed in the "smallArtName" array. The scheme looks like this:

> (key word) xxx (cordX|cordY)

I can't convert the string I received to a number. It seems to me that the reason is white space, visible in the terminal in the picture. I tried to use the replace method which works for sample text, but not for my value.

I'm a beginner and I could probably do it simpler, but the code I wrote works, and this is the most important thing for now.

```
for (i = 0; i < smallArtName.length; i++) {
   var n = art.artPrintScreen.indexOf(smallArtName[i]);
   if (n > 0) {
    var tempString = art.artPrintScreen.substring(n, n + 100);
    betweenChar = tempString.indexOf('|');
    for (k = betweenChar - 10; k <= betweenChar + 10; k++) {
     if (tempString[k] == '(') {
      xStart = k;
     }
     if (tempString[k] == ')') {
      yEnd = k;
     }
    }
    cordX = tempString.slice(xStart + 1, betweenChar);
    cordY = tempString.slice(betweenChar + 1, yEnd);

    strTest = "  t est".replace(/\s/g, '')
    var cordY2 = cordY.replace(/\s/g, '')

    console.log(typeof (cordY))
    console.log(cordY2)
    console.log(cordY2[0])
    console.log(cordY2[1])
    console.log(cordY2[2])
    console.log(cordY2[3])
    console.log(cordY2[4])
    console.log(cordY2[5])

    console.log(strTest)

    var cordYtest = parseInt(cordY2, 10);
    console.log(cordYtest)
   }
  }
```

[image: Text]

Comment: I don't see anything trying to be converted to a number in the code you provided. Also, where does the string come from? It seems like you might have some non-space character after the `-`, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: I corrected the post. If there are any questions I will gladly answer

Comment: @Fraser: That'll also remove negative signs.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - ah yes - they probably want - `var cordY2.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '')` - i.e. digits and negative sign. Will leave it as an answer 
 and delete the other comment to save any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the regex so that you replace everything except digits and the negative sign - rather than just whitespace. i.e.

change

```
var cordY2 = cordY.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

to

```
var cordY2 = parseInt(cordY.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''), 10);
```

So that the variable `cordY2` contains the number you require.